# Copy Azure Hyperscale DB

Tags: azure-sql-database

I need to copy a Hyperscale DB to another server in the same region/location, (the copy function is in coming soon state but not already available) does someone know how?

Answer (score 2):

Database copy for Hyperscale is now in Public Preview as announced [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-database/database-copy-preview-on-azure-sql-database-hyperscale/ba-p/1623866?wt.mc_id=MVP) on Sep 22, 2020.

If you don't like the current functionality, another option is creating a new database by restoring an existing backup.

When a copy is needed to another region use a geo-restore of the database. Create a SQL Database server in the target region if you do not already have an appropriate server there. This server should be owned by the same subscription as the original (source) server. Finally perform steps provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-recovery-using-backups#geo-restore).

Comment: This article shows you a restore using PowerShell https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4794/using-powershell-to-restore-an-azure-sql-database/